# Lua - find out calling function

Tags: function, lua

In Lua, is it possible to know which function has called the current function.

For instance

```
function a()
    get_calling_function()    --Should print function b
end 


function b()
    a() 
end
```

Is something like this possible?
Does the debug library have such functionality?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use `debug.traceback()`:

```
function a()
    print(debug.traceback())
end 


function b()
    a() 
end 

b()
```

which would print:

```
stack traceback:
    ./test.lua:45: in function 'a'
    ./test.lua:50: in function 'b'
    ./test.lua:53: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use debug.sethook() to set up a hook that gets called each time certain special events happen in lua. it can be useful for things like this.

```
local debugInfo = { caller = nil, callee = nil }
function hook()
    local info = debug.getinfo(2)
    if info == nil then
        debugInfo.callee = nil
        return
    end

    -- we only want to watch lua function calls (not C functions)
    if info.what ~= "Lua" then
        debugInfo.callee = "C function"
        return
    end

    debugInfo.caller = debugInfo.callee
    debugInfo.callee = info.name
end


debug.sethook(hook, "c")

function caller1()
    if debugInfo.caller ~= nil and debugInfo.callee ~= nil then
        msg = debugInfo.callee.. " was called by ".. debugInfo.caller.. "!"
        print(msg)
    end
end

function caller2()
    caller1()
end


caller2()
```

this prints 'caller1 was called from caller2!'

debug.sethook can handle 3 different characters in the second parameter so you can let it know when to notify you. 'c' means call your hook function any time a function is called in lua, 'r' means call  your hook function every time a function returns in lua, and 'l' means call your hook function whenever lua processes a new line of code.

you could set this up to build your own custom stack trace if you really wanted to, and you could also use debug.getlocal() within your hook to even try to work out what arguments were passed to your called function.

edit for lhf. this is actually a much simpler way of doing what you're asking, if you don't need to track this and just need to know the context of how the function was called.

```
function caller1()
    local current_func = debug.getinfo(1)
    local calling_func = debug.getinfo(2)
    print(current_func.name.. " was called by ".. calling_func.name.. "!")
end

function caller2()
    caller1()
end
```

Comment: You don't need to call `debug.getinfo` inside a hook. You can call  `debug.getinfo` inside your function directly.

Comment: ha, you're right. i over-engineered it. i'll add a snippet showing the easier way.

Comment: With tail-call optimization, the simpler version might give incorrect results if `caller2`'s call to `caller1` ends up tail-call optimized, since it prevents an addition to the call stack.